# React Native Device Manufacturer Info

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Having trouble finding the device manufacturer info. I used react-native-device-info library and it returns output as seen below. I am assuming the promise handling is incorrect.

**I want to get the value of device manufacturer in a variable.**

```
    const getDeviceManufacturer = async() => {  
      const deviceManufacturer = await DeviceInfo.getManufacturer((manufacturer) => { return manufacturer;})
      console.log('outside => ' + deviceManufacturer);
      return deviceManufacturer;
    }
    
    console.log('manufacturer', getDeviceManufacturer());
```

Console Log Output:

```
         LOG      manufacturer {"_40": 0, "_55": null, "_65": 0, "_72": null}
         LOG      outside => Google
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also write it with a then block without async/await as following:

```
DeviceInfo.getManufacturer().then(manufacturer => {
  console.log("manufacturer", manufacturer);
});
```

In your code this would be working too:

```
const getDeviceManufacturer = async() => {  
  const deviceManufacturer = await DeviceInfo.getManufacturer();
  return deviceManufacturer;
}
```

Comment: The second part doesn't work, i already tried it. The first one does but, I want to read it into a variable string from the promise return.